# JS>onClick>getElementById + Iterate

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, getelementbyid

I'm a novice so apologies if this is a daft question.

I have a series of button's that I want to "show" it's child element onclick.

I can get this to work for the first example perfectly, however I cannot figure out: how to get each button to relate to its child element?

```js
function unhide(data, otherData) {
  // for( var i = 1; i++ ) {
    var item = document.getElementById("about");
        // for (var i = 0; unhide = document.getElementById("about" + i); i++) {
     if (item)  {
            item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
        }
        document.getElementById(data +1).innerText = 'hidden';
    }
```

```html
  
<!-- -->  
<button onclick="unhide()">Add new rider</button>
<!-- -->


<div id="data">
    <form id="person">
    <div id="about" class="hidden">
        <br>

        
        <font color="blue" size="2"><br>Name:</font>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
        <br>
        
        <font color="blue" size="2">
        <br>Age: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        </font>
        <input id="age" name="age" type="text">
        <br>

        <font color="blue" size="2">
        <br>Height: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        </font>
        <input id="height" name="height" type="text">
        <br>

        <font color="blue" size="2"> 
        <br>Weight: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        </font>
        <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text">
        <br>

        <font color="blue" size="2">
        <br>Rider Level: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        </font>
        <select id="city" name="city">
            <option>CC1</option>
            <option>CC2</option>
            <option>CC3</option>
        </select>
        <br>
```

Comment: use forEach function

Comment: u have a button. On clicking the button u want to show the child elements. can u give details about what those child elements you are trying show and the structure of the parent and child elements data.

Comment: Hi!

Yes I am trying to show and hide a <form>data</form>

I can get this to work fine, I just don't know how to loop through each relationship of button(unique ID)+form(unique ID)?

Comment: Please, share the rendered html of the form to us, will be much easier to help

Comment: it's not clear which `buttons` are you talking about...I saw just one and it doesn't have any childs

Comment: <button onclick="unhide()">Add new rider</button>

I need the Button to be remote from the Form

The Form is to appear within a table, the button is to be separate (for the sake of intuitive UI)

How do I link the button to the form whilst triggering the function using the ID "about"?

Apologies if I'm not explaining this very well :/

Comment: I'll try to answer, but I still don't understand exactly your need

Comment: on button click use $(this).parents().find('form')